# Refactoring inheritance into templates while retaining certain characteristics

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following structure:

```
class Base {
   virtual T foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
   T foo() override { /**/ }
}

class Derived1 : public Base {
   T foo() override { /**/ }
}
```

I need the following to work (or an adequate substitute):

```
some_container<unique_ptr<Base>> objects;
```

Basically,
C++ AMP doesn't allow for virtual functions in kernels, but I definitely need an inheritance chain-like container behaviour.

What is a recommended / common pattern to transform this sort of inheritance chain to template magic?

Comment: Take a look at `boost::variant`. That might be helpful in order to have a common list of different types.

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859699/c-generating-an-interface-without-virtual-functions/18859931#18859931 Let me know if you think it's a dupe! (And hi! Gauntlet still there?)

Comment: Gauntlet still on the ground, just a tad busy with life :). The linked thing has some useful ideas, I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @sehe Oh ye, the boost::variant will likely do, thanks.

Comment: Or this somewhat [similar discussion/example in the lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12376009#12376009) (also links to the all important Sean Parent talk ["Inheritance Is The Base Class of Evil"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil))

Answer (score 1):

The canonical method to remove a vtable call is to replace it with a switch statement:

```
enum type_e
{
   type_derived,
   type_derived1
};

class Base
{
public:
   Base( type_e type ) : m_type( type ) {}

   T foo();

private:
   type_e m_type;
};


T Base::Foo()
{
   switch( m_type )
   {
   case type_derived:
      return //{...} your Derived::Foo()
   case type_derived1:
      return //{...} your Derived1::Foo()
   }
}
```

The only change in the API is that instead of call `new Derived()` you must call `new Base( type_derived )`. The major disadvantage is that you now have to hold all of your additional data (formerly members of Derived1 or Derived) in `Base`, which may bloat the class. On the other hand you can now make a container of Base by value, and avoid the overhead of `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own, manual vtable emulation:

```
class Base {
protected:
    using fp_t = int(*)(Base*);
    fp_t fp;
    Base( fp_t p ) : fp( p ) {}     
public:
    int foo() { return (*fp)(this); }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    static int sfoo(Base* b) { return static_cast<Derived*>(b)->foo(); }
    int foo() { return 42; }
public:
    Derived() : Base(&sfoo) {}
};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/497b602e7177414b)

Comment: Yeah, that looks like sane. I actually don't know what the problem with CUDA is; as it stands, you'll still need to have dynamic allocation in the device memory, which I imagine to be the hard part.

Comment: @KerrekSB It looks like there is a problem with functional calls in general on the GPU as there is no notion of stack. It seems that everything is strictly inlined and de-virtualizing calls, whenever not impossible, is difficult.