# C++ multimethods and compile time detection

Tags: c++, multimethod

I have the following code :

```
class A{};
class B: public A{};
class C: public A{};

class MyVisitor
{
   public:
       void visit(B*);
       void visit(C*);
};
```

And then collection of A* objects, I want to achieve the following :

1)

```
MyVisitor visitor;
for(vector<A*>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it!= vec.end();it++)
     visitor->visit(a);
```

2) Somehow determine at compile time, if A* points to derived object D,and give compiler error, if `MyVisitor::visit(D*)` function is not present

I know that 1) is achievable with some multimethods implementation, I guess I can find some implementations of multimethods for c++ . But is 2) somehow possible ?

Comment: By "multimethod" I assume you mean polymorphic cast? Do you come from a Clojure background?

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar multimethods are a language agnostic notion (a.k.a. multiple dispatch)

Comment: Regardless, there is no way to determine (within c++'s type system at least) whether or not some arbitrary INSTANCE of a class is a derived or base class at COMPILE time after instantiation.

Comment: It misses the `accept` part in the hierarchy for the [Visitor_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Perhaps the techniques based on Boost Variant (with binary visitation) will interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859699/generating-an-interface-without-virtual-functions/18859931#18859931 (I can't find the other example that may have been a better match right now)

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at some projects I have developed: http://www.yorel.be/mm/, https://github.com/jll63/yomm11, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635264/Open-Multi-Methods-for-Cplusplus11-Part-1 It is an implementation of multi-methods for C++ that very much resembles Stroustrup & al's proposal. It is fast too, it beats double dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dynamic_cast` like this (inside the body of your `for` loop) since the behavior should vary at run-time (according to the actual type of data).

```
   ClassB* ba = dynamic_cast<ClassB*>(a);
   if (ba)
      visitor->visit(ba);
   ClassC* ca = dynamic_cast<ClassC*>(a);
   if (ca)
      visitor->visit(ca);
```

Maybe your `visit` functions might be declared `virtual` (for your `ClassD` thing).

Otherwise organize your classes as a tree (not a forest) of classes, and have your topmost root class

```
  class Topmost {
     virtual int classnum() const;
```

and adopt the *convention* that each non-abstract class gives its unique `classnum` etc... Or have a metaclass mechanism (like e.g. [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) has)

Comment: I want to avoid use of dynamic cast.

Comment: dynamic_cast operates at RUN-TIME not at compile time.

Comment: Why do you want to a void it? It is a good reason for using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    virtual void visit() = 0;
};
class B: private A
{
public:
    void visit()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};
class C: private A
{
public:
    void visit()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }    
};

template <typename... Args>
class MyVisitor : public Args...
{
   public:
       template <typename T>
           void visit(T* t)
       {
           t->visit();
       }
};

int main()
{
    MyVisitor<B, C> visitor;
    B b;
    B* bp = &b;
    visitor.visit(bp);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/live/FOSX19634)

Comment: Why the derivation from `Args...`? And you could pass any unrelated type that has a `visit` method, including something that doesn't derive from `A` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply the visitor pattern completly:

```
class B;
class C;

class IVisitor
{
public:
    void visit(B&) = 0;
    void visit(C&) = 0;
};

class A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void accept(IVisitor& v) = 0;
};

class B: public A{ void accept(IVisitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); } };
class C: public A{ void accept(IVisitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); } };
```