# Calling parametrised method on list items with different template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-any

I'm trying to store and manipulate a list of template class objects with different parameter types; the template class has two parametrised methods, one returning the parameter type and a *void* one accepting it as input.

More specifically, I have a template class defined as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    virtual T a() = 0;
    virtual void b(T t) = 0;
};
```

And different specifications of it, such as:

```
class TestInt : public Test<int>
{
public:
    int a() {
        return 1;
    }
    void b(int t) {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};

class TestString : public Test<std::string>
{
public:
    std::string a() {
        return "test";
    }
    void b(std::string t) {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I'd like to be able to store in one single list different objects of both `TestInt` and `TestString` type and loop through it calling one method as input for the other, as in:

```
for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
    (*it)->b((*it)->a());
```

I've looked into `boost::any` but I'm unable to cast the iterator to the specific class, because I don't know the specific parameter type of each stored object. Maybe this cannot be done in a statically typed language as C++, but I was wondering whether there could be a way around it.

Just for the sake of completeness, I'll add that my overall aim is to develop a "parametrised observer", namely being able to define an observer (as with the Observer Pattern) with different parameters: the `Test` class is the observer class, while the list of different types of observers that I'm trying to properly define is stored within the subject class, which notifies them all through the two methods `a()` and `b()`.

Comment: If you really only want to feed the output of the one member function to the other, then you should probably define a third member function to do exactly that. This function would then effectively hide the actually needed type from the caller, allowing you to stick with simple inheritance from an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtuals have actually no meaning here, since for each `T` the signatures are distinct.

So it seems you have Yet Another version of the eternal "how can we emulate virtual functions templates" or "how to create an interface without virtual functions":

- [Generating an interface without virtual functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859699/generating-an-interface-without-virtual-functions/18859931#18859931)
- [How to achieve "virtual template function" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871722/how-to-achieve-virtual-template-function-in-c/7629011#7629011)

The first one basically contains an idea that you could employ here.

Here's an idea of what I'd do:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea528cab21587186)</kbd>**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace mytypes {
    template <typename T>
    struct Test {
        T a() const;
        void b(T t) { std::cout << t << std::endl; } 
    };

    template <> int         Test<int>::a()         const { return 1;      }
    template <> std::string Test<std::string>::a() const { return "test"; }

    using TestInt    = Test<int>;
    using TestString = Test<std::string>;
}

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

namespace mytypes { 
    using Value = boost::variant<int, std::string>;

    namespace detail {
        struct a_f : boost::static_visitor<Value> {
            template <typename T>
            Value operator()(Test<T> const& o) const { return o.a(); }
        };
        struct b_f : boost::static_visitor<> {
            template <typename T>
            void operator()(Test<T>& o, T const& v) const { o.b(v); }

            template <typename T, typename V>
            void operator()(Test<T>&, V const&) const {
                throw std::runtime_error(std::string("type mismatch: ") + __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
            }
        };
    }

    template <typename O>
    Value a(O const& obj) {
        return boost::apply_visitor(detail::a_f{}, obj);
    }

    template <typename O, typename V>
    void b(O& obj, V const& v) {
        boost::apply_visitor(detail::b_f{}, obj, v);
    }
}

#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace mytypes;
    using AnyTest = boost::variant<TestInt, TestString>;

    std::vector<AnyTest> list{TestInt(), TestString(), TestInt(), TestString()};

    for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
        b(*it, a(*it));
}
```

This prints

```
1
test
1
test
```

---

### Bonus Points

If you insist, you can wrap the `AnyTest` variant into a proper class and have `a()` and `b(...)` member functions on that:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/064ebcb9dd02dbc9)</kbd>**

```
int main()
{
    using namespace mytypes;
    std::vector<AnyTest> list{AnyTest(TestInt()), AnyTest(TestString()), AnyTest(TestInt()), AnyTest(TestString())};

    for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
        it->b(it->a());
}
```

Comment: Great, now I know how people refer to this problem and I can dig into it :-) I think this is close to the solution I was looking for, except that I tried using boost::variant and it worked (somehow) but I wanted something more "general", so that I could add new TestWhatever classes without modifying the main file to support the Whatever type (editing the Test struct in this case). I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5872226/1873470) answer I've found among the links you've suggested might help me achieve what I want though.

Comment: @tturchi Note that my answer also shows the visitor pattern. As soon as you use the virtual interface, though, boost variant makes little sense anymore (either runtime or compile-time polymorphism will do; both is overkill)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment above, the simplest what I can currently think of to achieve what you are trying to do - at least as I understood it from your example code - is the following:

```
/* Interface for your container, better not forget the destructor! */
struct Test {
  virtual void operate(void) = 0;
  virtual ~Test() {}
};
/* Implementation hiding actual type */
template<typename T>
struct TestImpl : public T, public Test {
  void operate(void) {
    T::b(T::a());
  }
};

/* Actual code as template policies */
struct IntTest {
  int a(void) {
    return 42;
  }
  void b(int value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  }
};
struct StringTest {
  std::string a(void) {
    return "Life? Don't talk to me about life.";
  }
  void b(std::string value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  }
};
```

You would then need to create a container for objects of class `Test` and fill it with objects of the respective `TestImpl<IntTest>`, `TestImpl<StringTest>`, and so on. To avoid object slicing you need reference or pointer semantics, that is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test> >` for example.

```
for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {
  (*it)->operate();
}
```